# Why encode string with base64 if it can be easily decoded

Tags: elasticsearch, encoding, base64

There are algorithms for encoder which are impossible to hack and these encoder are used in applications like HTTPS for sending secure message over network. Base64 is very simple and can be easily decoded, I think encoding with base64 is as simple as sending raw data.
Then why base64 encoding is used? For example Elasticsearch automatically generates  id which is encoded with base64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base64 is not used for security at all, it is used as a means of escaping special characters.

see:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29916/why-does-http-basic-authentication-encode-the-username-and-password-with-base64

[What is the purpose of base 64 encoding and why it used in HTTP Basic Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070693/what-is-the-purpose-of-base-64-encoding-and-why-it-used-in-http-basic-authentica)

[Why Base64 in Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661384/why-base64-in-basic-authentication)

Comment: Great, thanks, that is why it is used to make string URL safe. So i think mostly usage will be in URLs. There is URLencoding API in Java that must be using base64.

Answer (score 1):

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a means to **encode** a series of bytes into a string. Useful if your transport, or storage, wants strings only.

For example, if you have a PDF file and you want to send it inside an XML document, you typically will base64 encode the PDF file bytes into a string, place that string in the XML document. Then the consumer does the reverse: string base64 decode to PDF file bytes.

Base64 is not encryption and serves no security purpose.

It is also not a means of "escaping" a string - although it can be used that way it would be unusual. Typically it is used to send a series of non-string bytes, as a string.