# Use different encryption algorithm in BIRT webapp

Tags: security, jetty, reporting, birt

I'm developing BIRT reports, which are deployed as a WEBAPP on Jetty.
Currently all the passwords in my Connection Provider Stores are Base64 'encrypted', but I'm wondering if and how I can use another encryption algorithm for my encrypted-properties.

```
<encrypted-property name="odaPassword" encryptionID="base64" value="......."/>
```

I've read something about Encryption Extension Points but I'm not sure if this concept also applies to BIRT webapps and how to implement this / where to put them.

Best regards,
Richard

Answer (score 3):

Base 64 is an encoding method, not an encryption method. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4070709/2782404. What are you currently using for encryption?

Have you seen this example of encryption extension point implementation for BIRT? http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1748986&seqNum=6

If so, source code might be helpful for understanding your specific problem

Comment: I know that Base64 is not an encryption method, but I wanted to use BIRTs own terminology to be clear about what I'm doing there.
Also I've seen this post, but I assume it refers to use another encryption algorithm in eclipse (because the plugin.xml is modified). But I want to use the (real) encryption algorithm within my webapp deployed on Jetty.
I'm not sure what kind of source code would be helpful here. In my project I have a rptlibrary file, which reads the connection information from a related cps file. In this file I want to use another 'encryption' algorithm then Base64.