# Why do we need boundaries in multipart data format?

Tags: java, http, multipartform-data, resttemplate

Title says it all.
I mean suppose we are trying to upload multiple images,
for each multipart section we will have sub-headers like

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mia.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 5379
```

Content-Length is enough to tell the parser when this content part is over
and starts another part.
But I'm missing something most likely, can you help ?

Comment: before parser can parse content-length it needs to split raw data into chunks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Content-Length` isn't a requirement of multipart content. This issue of using lengths is addressed in part [the old RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388):

> **5.2 Other data encodings rather than multipart**

> Various people have suggested using new mime top-level type
> "aggregate", e.g., aggregate/mixed or a content-transfer-encoding of
> "packet" to express indeterminate-length binary data, rather than
> relying on the multipart-style boundaries. While this would be
> useful, the "multipart" mechanisms are well established, simple to
> implement on both the sending client and receiving server, and as
> efficient as other methods of dealing with multiple combinations of
> binary data.

That text isn't in the [current one](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578), though; `length` doesn't appear in it at all.

This makes particular sense if you consider a sender sending the result of a stream as one part of a multipart post, when it may not know in advance the lenth of that stream's data. If length were required, it would need to either cache or read twice.

Comment: yes it makes sense, so even omitting length servers should be able to decode the multipart data, because their parsing algorith is based on boundaries rather than counting bytes ?

Comment: @GionJh - Right.

Comment: one last thing, I 've read somewhere (don't remember the source sorry) that sending binary data in multi-part-format is not a good thing and you should encode it in Base64, what do you think ?

Comment: @GionJh - I have no special knowledge about that, sorry.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You've picked a long outdated RFC. Check the RFC 7578 for a current documentation.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin - Thanks, first one I found, as surprisingly I don't have these memorized. :-)

Comment: @GionJh concerning base64 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538021/why-do-we-use-base64 as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070693/what-is-the-purpose-of-base-64-encoding-and-why-it-used-in-http-basic-authentica and base64 or multi-part is not an either or as they can be used together. They solve different problems. Something sent as base64 is just another document.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need boundaries in multipart data format?

Boundaries are delimiters meant to allow the server to split the message into chunks or body parts. A multipart request can contain any arbitrary number of body parts. The `multipart/form-data` requests are currently defined in the [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578).

Each part consists of its own content header (zero or more `Content-` header fields) and a body. It's also important to mention that the boundary delimiter must not appear inside any of the encapsulated parts.

Another relevant document is the [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046), which defines multipart MIME data streams:

> The body must then contain one or more body parts, each preceded by a boundary delimiter line, and the last one followed by a closing boundary delimiter line. After its boundary delimiter line, each body part then consists of a header area, a blank line, and a body area.