# What could be used instead of Shared Preferences for storing user information??As People says Shared Preference is not Secure

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-storage

What could be used instead of Shared Preferences for storing user information? People say Shared Preference is not Secure.

Comment: you can't just collect all possible ways here. Also, if `Shared Preferences` is not secure, then make it secured yourself - encrypt the values

Comment: @TejasJoshi SharedPreferences is not for storing user information, it generally used for holding some small values. For storing user information you can go for database depends upon your app

Comment: have a look at [other options to store data.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

Comment: @RishavSingla Android Shared Preference are name-value pair saved as XML files. Majorly used to save user’s app preference or user’s details or state of the app by developers. Shared Preference are files which are saved inside directory named shared_prefs present within App Sandbox i.e.  /data/data/AppPackageName/shared_prefs .

Comment: @TejasJoshi i already know it, but user information can be long as much as possible, or user can change it also, and you have to get that information whereever in app, so shared preference is not a good idea..go for https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/  , its secure private database

Comment: @TejasJoshi if you want to use sharedpreference then use Base64 encryption , this link will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148729/how-to-secure-android-shared-preferences

Comment: Ty @RishavSingla but Base64 ??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070693/what-is-the-purpose-of-base-64-encoding-and-why-it-used-in-http-basic-authentica

Comment: Who says (private) SharedPreferences is not secure? Android apps are sandboxed and, therefore, other applications can't access its internal data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SQLCipher` library for encrypted database or encrypt/decrypt values yourself with some key and store result in `SharedPreferences`. To store keys use [Android keystone system](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore).

Comment: Android keystone system. not found

Comment: for store user information, this is not a recommended one to use this for security purpose, i suggest to use https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/ , its private database

Comment: @RishavSingla A room database is stored in the app's internal storage. This is no different than SharedPreferences. I see no reason why Room would be more secure than SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing information in the users' device, no approach is 100% secure. You can hide the information in some ways (eg. encoding, encryption, etc) but still won't be 100% secure.

In order to make your information secure, you will need to store the information in a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Shared Preferences are stored as a file in the filesystem on the device. They are, by default, stored within the app's data directory with filesystem premissions set that only allow the UID that the specific application runs with to access them. So, they are private in so much as Linux file permissions restrict access to them, the same as on any Linux/Unix system.

Anyone with root level access to the device will be able to see them, as root has access to everything on the filesystem. Also, any application that runs with the same UID as the creating app would be able to access them (this is not usually done and you need to take specific action to make two apps runs with the same UID, so this is probably not a big concern). Finally, if someone was able to mount your device's filesystem without using the installed Android OS, they could also bypass the permissions that restrict access.

**If you're concerned about such access to your preferences (or any data written by your application), then you will want to encrypt it. If you are that concerned about them, you're going to need to figure out exactly how much protection is necessary for the level of risk you see.**

You can also use Database with encryption like whatsapp. Its a best way for security point of view. If you want you can hide the Database also.

Comment: If you encrypt it, then where do you put the encryption key? If they key is stored on the device (in the case of KeyStore), then root can just use the encryption key and decrypt the data.